# implementing pygtk and matplotlib together

Tags: matplotlib, pygtk

I want to write a program to plot different graphs from user input. I only know how to use pygtk and matplotlib. Are there any ways for me to implement these two module together to create such kind of programs? If not, what should I use? I also heard that pygtk is not common anymore. Which module is the most popular among all(for writing gui)?

Comment: There are examples of how to use these modules together on the [matplotlib site](http://matplotlib.org/examples/user_interfaces/embedding_in_gtk.html). The rest of your question is not very specific. PyGTK is not up to date and you should rather use PyGObject.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably not use PyGTK anymore, but the newer GTK+-API which is called PyGObject. I have some tutorials here:

- [GTK3-Matplotlib-Cookbook](https://github.com/tobias47n9e/GTK3-Matplotlib-Cookbook)

And this program is written the same way:

- [A PyGObject program](https://github.com/tobias47n9e/innstereo)